# Dynamic client using JaxWsDynamicClientFactory generates java.lang.IllegalArgumentException error

Tags: java, web-services, maven, bundle, karaf

I am a one more noobie in web service programming who faced an unknown error:

I am trying to use JaxWsDynamicClientFactory in order to invoke dynamically the requested service (the address of the service and its parameters are read from a file, but this is irrelevant here).

The problem is caused by this standard initialisation of JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.

```
JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dcf= JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
```

After execution of this line Karaf (Felix) returns the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set final com.sun.tools.internal.xjc
.reader.internalizer.InternalizationLogic field com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.reade
r.internalizer.DOMForest.logic to org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientF
actory$1
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(
UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:146)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(
UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:150)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeQualifiedObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeQualifie
dObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:65)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:657)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory.hackInNewInterna
lizationLogic(DynamicClientFactory.java:817)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory.createClient(Dyn
amicClientFactory.java:314)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory.createClient(Dyn
amicClientFactory.java:270)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory.createClient(Dyn
amicClientFactory.java:263)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory.createClient(Dyn
amicClientFactory.java:198)
        at testclient.BundleInvoker.invoke(BundleInvoker.java:53)
        at testclient.TestClient.activate(TestClient.java:67)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invokeMethod(BaseMethod.j
ava:236)
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.access$500(BaseMethod.jav
a:37)
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod$Resolved.invoke(BaseMetho
d.java:613)
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invoke(BaseMethod.java:49
6)
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.ActivateMethod.invoke(ActivateMethod
.java:149)
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ImmediateComponentManager.createImp
lementationObject(ImmediateComponentManager.java:239)
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ImmediateComponentManager.createCom
ponent(ImmediateComponentManager.java:119)
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager$Unsatisfie
d.activate(AbstractComponentManager.java:1518)
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.activateIn
ternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:550)
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.enable(Abs
tractComponentManager.java:261)
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.config.ImmediateComponentHolder.enableCompo
nents(ImmediateComponentHolder.java:328)
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.initialize(BundleC
omponentActivator.java:158)
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.<init>(BundleCompo
nentActivator.java:113)
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.loadComponents(Activator.java:261
)
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.bundleChanged(Activator.java:179)

        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEv
ent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventM
anager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchr
onous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEvent
Privileged(Framework.java:1569)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEvent
(Framework.java:1505)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEvent
(Framework.java:1500)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(Bundl
eHost.java:391)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(Abstrac
tBundle.java:300)
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(Di
rectoryWatcher.java:1247)
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(D
irectoryWatcher.java:1219)
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startAllBundle
s(DirectoryWatcher.java:1208)
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(Direct
oryWatcher.java:503)
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryW
atcher.java:291)
```

In fact, I have no problem with the following execution (the program continue without any effect), but I would like to remove this nasty stack of errors from the screen. I tried to hide the error by try-catch environment, but Karaf simply ignores it (i.e., does not trigger catch part, although prints the whole stack).

*Could you help me to solve the problem (or at least help to understand why this simple line generates it)?*

In general. Code is created in Eclipse Kepler, built with Maven 2, and executed in Karaf (felix). Here is the dependency part from the pom file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>my.test.bundle</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-interface</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.felix.framework</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0</version>
    <type>bundle</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <type>bundle</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the [CXF website](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/dynamic-clients.html)!

> Note that, in general, CXF only supports WSI-BP services. If you attempt to create a
>   dynamic client for a WSDL that uses features outside of WSI-BP, CXF may throw an exception.

This might be your problem. Check it with tools like SOAPUI were you right-click the binding and select : Check WSI Compliance

Answer (score 0):

I get the same exception, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException, when creating a dynmaic client for a WSDL that is WS-I conformant. I believe the problem reported here :

[IllegalArgumentException when using JaxWsDynamicClientFactory](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/201405.mbox/%3C485892C1-A229-424F-84E0-C3E2C8D6AE32@apache.org%3E)

is the reason.

Comment: This post doesn't provide an answer.